# Are “keep up with/ keep pace with/ catch up with” the same in use? Which is correct one in the following context?

Tags: word-choice

She tries to study hard to keep​ ……….       her classmates.  ​

```
A. up with        ​​​     ​B. pace with ​
C. out of​​​​​               D. on with
```

Answer (score 1):

"keep up with" and "keep pace with" both have more or less the same meaning like progressing at the same rate as someone or something else.

While using "keep up with" and "keep pace with", suggests that both parties are already on the same level.

"Catch up with" has the meaning that you are trying to reach a person who is already ahead of you.

So in this context, A. up with,  would be the wise choice. Keep pace with is not widely used.

She tries to study hard to keep​ …up with……. her classmates. ​

Comment: Hi Megha, welcome to our site! It's worth reading the EL&U help centre's page on [what's "on topic"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), since providing an answer to an off-topic question is generally frowned upon, with the risk of receiving downvotes. Questions about learner-level English are nearly always off-topic. However, we try not to downvote new contributors, since there's a lot to learn on our site and our primary rule is "Be Nice". :-)